# Only echo works in this code in this if statement (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', '*mypass*', 'login');

$check = "SELECT * FROM users";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $username = strtolower($_POST['username']);

            $password = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);

            if($username && $password){
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
                    if($username == $data[1]){
                        if($password == $data[2]){
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                            $exp = time() + (60*60*24*365);
                            setcookie('user', $username, $exp);
                            echo "test";
                            header("location: dash.php");
                            exit();
                        } else {
                            error("Incorrect Password");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                error("Please insert your username and password");
            }
        }
```

In this code, the content of the if statement ( if($password == $data[2]) ) doesn't run correctly: only the echo function works, all the other doesn't!

Is there a solution to this issue?

I use PHP 7.0

POST:

- `echo "test";` was added only for testings purposes, the code doesn't work with or without it.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at this part:

```
 if($username && $password){
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
                    if($username == $data[1]){
                        if($password == $data[2]){
```

You should be careful when reading `$data`. Put simply, the `$data` array is indexed on a per-row basis starting from 0, so `$data[1]` and `$data[2]` refer to the entire second and third resultset rows, but you're not actually reading any result fields.

The right and cleaner way would be:

```
if($username && $password){
  $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
  foreach ($data as $row)
  {
    $username = $row['field_name_with_username];
    $password = $row['field_name_with_password];

    ... then whatever you need to do afterwards with those variables

  }
```

If you rather stay away from the foreach looping, you can use while or for, but you need to define an interation counter (i.e. `$i = 0;` before entering the loop and `$i++;` just before the end of each iteration) and on each pass access `$data[$i]['field_name_with_username']` and `$data[$i]['field_name_with_password']`

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array defaults to give you a choice of numeric or field names for indices.  It's a matter of taste.

Comment: There is no need to fetch a  row then iterate through the row here (I doubt it will work as the keys will not exist).  It looks as if you are mistaking `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_all`.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer but something to try to check sessions are working.

Place the following code in its own file:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['test_counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['test_counter']++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['test_counter'] = 1;
}    

echo $_SESSION['test_counter'];
```

It should first display 1, and then increment the integer upon refresh.